# Backup an external drive to an external drive - windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup

Is it possible?
I've tried adding the external drive (i.e., drive to be backed up) in Windows backup options, but I just get an error (0x80070032).

If it matters, I'm using an HDD for backup, and an SSD that needs to be backed up.

Comment: I have the same problem, it'd be great if you could answer the question if you already figured out how to fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across "AOMEI Backupper". It does the job, and actually did save me from losing 6 months of work (from home). However, I ended up just buying a bigger SSD and backing up to an external SSD (so I have a portable copy if needed).

AOMEI works, but is a little "rough around the edges", if you know what I mean..